# How to create a config file and access in FitNesse?

Tags: java, fitnesse

How do I create a config file and call within FitNesse test suites in Java?

I have multiple FitNesse test suites with repeating url link, and I would like to move those url to a config file and call directly within the FitNesse test suites.

Sample FitNesse tests:

```
|request payload |${post}|
|keyTab url| 'home/data/file'|
|url|https://google.com|
```

Recurring URL in all FitNesse tests:

```
|keyTab url| 'home/data/file'|
|url|https://google.com|
```

Trying to move the recurring URLs to a config file and call the file within all the FitNesse tests.

1. How do I create a XML (config) file for the URLs?
2. How do I call the XML file in FitNesse Test Suites?

Comment: Did you check http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.AdministeringFitNesse.ConfigurationFile official documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be XML? That would require a custom fixture.

FitNesse does provide the option to load a configuration file that you can provide with the -f filename.properties command line argument (default: plugins.properties).

Apart from FitNesse's own configuration properties, any custom property you provide here, can be accessed using ${propertyName} in the wiki and will be translated to its value.

Comment: It doesn't have to be XML; can be anything

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a separate file, outside the wiki? Otherwise I would recommend just defining the repeating config values in the top-level page of your suite using `!define KEY_TAB_FILE {'home/data/file'}`. Then all test pages can just use `${KEY_TAB_FILE}` to access the value.

In parent page:

```
!define KEY_TAB_FILE {'home/data/file'}
!define URL {https://google.com}
```

In test pages the values are specified using these values

```
|request payload |${post}|
|keyTab url|${KEY_TAB_FILE}|
|url|${URL}|
```

With this approach you can also reuse the test pages for different environments using [symbolic links](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.FitNesseWiki.SymbolicLinks) (e.g. different URLs to test). The same test pages are linked between different root pages that specify different values for the parameters.